# Date Picker in Adapter class showing error

Tags: android, date, window, picker

may be possible, it is duplicate question but I did not find solution for it I'm using date picker in Adapter class whenever I click on TextView, date picker showing error

> `Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

I Have searched for it on Stack Overflow I got the solution but it is working on some devices only,

```
 private String dateDialouge(final BwViewHolder feedListRowHolder) {


    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            dateTime = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            feedListRowHolder.tv_date.setText(dateTime);

        }
    }, year, month, date);

    //setDate = feedListRowHolder.tv_date.getText().toString();
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDay);  // 24 hours
    datePickerDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    //WindowManager.LayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    datePickerDialog.show();

    return dateTime;
}
```

when i use window type `datePickerDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);`
it is working on Nougat but not working on some devices .

when i use

> `datePickerDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`

it will show error `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application in adapter class`

the permissions are taken

```
<uses-permission android:name="INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW "/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

have a look on my constructer

```
  public BoxServicesAdapter(Activity activity,Context context, List<BoxServicesBean> feedItemList, String service_id, String service_title) {
    this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.service_id = service_id;
    this.service_title = service_title;
    this.boxadapter = this;
    this.activity=activity;}
```

Comment: can you place the code where you are calling `datePickerDialog()`

Comment: @abdul i edit the code

Comment: what is `activity` ??  what context does it have?

Comment: @abdul have a look on my constructor

Answer (score 1):

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST`
This constant was deprecated in API level 26. for non-system apps. Use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` instead.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
```

> This constant was deprecated in API level 26. for non-system apps. Use
>   `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` instead.

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST` Requires S`YSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission`.

Comment: i used it TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT but i have taken permission in main-feast, but it is showing error "permission denied for window type 2003" it is necessary to take run time permission

Comment: would you try WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST and use the   SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission

Comment: i tried TYPE_TOAST  and it is working but some of device not showing date picker,

Comment: could you please provide the details of devices which it is not working.

Comment: have u seen this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Comment: Xiomi Note, I don't have full configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165279/discussion-between-sovereign-and-lib4).